# Error while creating a package2 version in DX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

While creating a version for the package2 , I am running into errors

example of the errors :Unknown config name "packageDirectories". 
                       Unknown config name "namespace".

Following is the content of the sfdx-config.json

```
{
     "packageDirectories": [        
     {
            "path": "force-app", "default": true,
            "id": "0Ho1p0000004C93CAE",
            "versionName": "None",
            "versionDescription": "None",
            "versionNumber": "None",
            "dependencies": "None"
},        
    {
            "path": "force-app", "default": true        },
    {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "id": "<package2 id 0Ho1p0000004C93CAE>",
            "versionName": "Summer 17 Rel",
            "versionDescription": "Common Package",
            "versionNumber": "1.3.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId": "None",
            "features": "None",
            "orgPreferences": 
            {
                "enabled": [
                    "S1DesktopEnabled",
                    "NetworksEnabled",
                    "Translation"    
                ],
                "disabled": [] 
        }
    }   ],

     "namespace": "",
     "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
     "sourceApiVersion": "42.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the same path more than once, and you can't set more than one path as default. I suspect that you're simply confusing the system and the errors you're getting are just a byproduct of confusing the system. Try cleaning everything up and trying again. Make sure you use unique path names, and set exactly one as default.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your reply , I have cleaned up the the json and it looks like below.{
     "namespace": "",
     "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
     "sourceApiVersion": "42.0",

     "packageDirectories": [        
     {
            "path": "force-app", "default": true,
            "id": "0Ho1p0000004C93CAE",
            "versionName": "None",
            "versionDescription": "None",
            "versionNumber": "None",
            "dependencies": "None"
}        
    
 ]
 
 
}

Comment: With the above json , am still running into the error unknown config name "namespace"

Comment: @achilles3339 I think you can remove the namespace, since you're not using it.